# Cypress verification timed out after 30000 milliseconds

Tags: node.js, npm, cypress

I am using cypress 5.0 in JS project. When I try to run `npx cypress open` keep getting error `verification timed out after 30000 milliseconds`.

Node version: v12.18.2
OS: Windows 7
Cypress : 5.0.0

I have downgraded to Cypress 4.0.0 and downgraded my node too. But keep getting the error. Please find the screenshot below. 2

[image]

Comment: If you say you downgraded to 4.0.0 but is still getting the same error, it means it hasn't really been downgraded and it's still running 5.0.0
Did you run `npm prune` and `npm install` as part of the downgrade?

Comment: Deleting the existing `node_modules` local project folder and reinstalling again with `npm install` made it work for me!

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Retrying launching `Cypress` one more time worked out with the error being gone, hmm...

Comment: Same situation here, hmm

Comment: worked! same behavior...

Comment: Looks like `Cypress` isn't a stable tool, still ;-)

Comment: When I ran the `open` command a **second** time, it worked (as Daniel suggests here!), but it still gives me the message: "It looks like this is your **first** time using Cypress: 9.1.0"

Comment: Applicable to nwrl application launch (angular)

Answer (score 86):

I had a similar issue and I used the `npx cypress verify`  to carry out the verification.

This happens because there's a verification that's meant to happen for first-time users but for some reason, the verification process times out.so one way to make the verification work is by using the npx cypress verify package.

Comment: According to the `cypress` command list; `verify` "Verifies that Cypress is installed correctly and executable"

Comment: Every for me the individual `verify` command failed with a timeout message; in the end, I just **retried** the `open` command (as suggested in the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67263055/1175496)) and cypress test runner opened...

Comment: this worked for me increasing execution time don't work as few of them answered them below

Comment: > npx cypress verify  is MUST to do.

Answer (score 39):

This issue is not related to Cypress version. To resolve it, you need to increase the default timeout.

Open `node_modules\cypress\lib\tasks\verify.js`, search for `VERIFY_TEST_RUNNER_TIMEOUT_MS` and change it from `30000` (default) to `100000`.

Save the file, then try to open the runner.

Comment: here is a direct link to that line https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/blob/develop/cli/lib/tasks/verify.js#L18

Comment: Is there a way to do this without modifying verify.js inside the node_modules?

Comment: I tried many solutions and this one worked for me. I did not want to fix it in this way. However there is not other way out. Ideally we should not be changing these modules that are shipped with Cypress. If some can post a better way of doing this it would be great.

Comment: This worked for me also, while I agree we "shouldnt" be changing settings on packages, I feel like this potentially exposes a bug and an issue can be raised.

Comment: To avoid modifying the `verify.js` file, simply run `export CYPRESS_VERIFY_TIMEOUT=100000` in your terminal and re-run `npx cypress verify`. The longer timeout will be used.

Comment: this worked for me, increasing timeout in verify.js worked like i charm for me, thank you so much

Comment: As we don't need this timeout hanging around beyond the single run, it may be better to avoid using export and do this: `CYPRESS_VERIFY_TIMEOUT=100000 npx cypress verify` instead

Answer (score 12):

From Cypress version [`9.2.0`](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/changelog#9-2-0), you no longer have to change the timeout value in `node_modules\cypress\lib\tasks\verify.js` file manually.

Instead, you can utilize an environment variable called `CYPRESS_VERIFY_TIMEOUT` "to override the timeout duration of the verify command". Here is the [link](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/guides/command-line#cypress-verify) to the documentation about `cypress verify` command that mentions it.

Even better, starting from version [`9.3.0`](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/changelog#9-3-0), we can set the environment variable in a project's package.json or .npmrc (or .yarnrc) file.

Using this environment variable to increase the timeout (3 minutes for us) was necessary for us to ensure stability in our CI testing pipeline.

Answer (score 8):

I had the same problem, running Cypress in WSL 2 would throw the same error even after trying all the solutions here.

I realised my Xserver was not running, started it up and everything worked again.

Comment: In WSL 2 you need to have Xserver running **if** you have `DISPLAY` env variable set. So either start Xserver or unset the variable by running `DISPLAY= npx cypress open`. However, you probably want to start the Xserver to actually use Cypress.

Answer (score 5):

Rerun it. It will work.
Rerunning it verified the cypress.

Answer (score 2):

Please try this
go to path: `node_modules\cypress\lib\tasks\verify.js`, and you need to increase the default timeout.

Open verify.js, search for the variable `VERIFY_TEST_RUNNER_TIMEOUT_MS`. By default it should be 30000. Change it to 100000.

Save and try to open the runner. I hope now you will able to run the tests.

Comment: I try but no avail

Comment: This is a duplicate of @KumarGaurav's answer.

Answer (score 0):

I also got this error , so I relaunch the cypress again(Which works for me) and also to be on safe side i have change the default duration with 100000s for future.

Comment: This is a duplicate of @KumarGaurav's answer.  And less detailed.

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same problem, I solved it just by disabling the antivirus [Windows 10].

Answer (score 0):

1st time using this tool today on my CentOS system.
Got the same error when trying to run cypress open and cypress verify.
Tried clearing the cache, reinstalling and all that fun stuff.
Nothing fixed it.

Note: I had VSCode running on my system and I had recently started the Angular ng test to test other tests.

**Apparently something with ng test interferes with Cypress.** Once I turned off ng test and tried to open and verify Cypress it worked.

Cypress 9.1.1

Answer (score 0):

Problem with Windows was restarting the terminal, probably the PATH was not correctly updated.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the problem by restarting the vs code and run again.
WSL2

Answer (score -1):

To resolve this issue, you need to increase default timeout. For this, go to below path: node_modules\cypress\lib\tasks\verify.js & Open verify.js, search variable VERIFY_TEST_RUNNER_TIMEOUT_MS. By default it should be 30000. Change it to 100000.

Comment: This is a duplicate of @KumarGaurav's answer.

Answer (score -1):

It's all due the `Cache`. Clear the cache it will automatically set.
I got the solution from this article. Follow the last step:

```
npm cache clean --force
```

https://softans.com/clear-cache-file-in-cypress/