# Cypress runing failed

Tags: installation, cypress, failed-installation, npm-start, cypress-component-test-runner

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/70EyU.jpg)[timed out](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VNQRD.jpg)
i would run cypress on my project (under linux) but it failed with timed out notice. i tried all the solutions i have red in the web but still encounter this issue. Can you please help me it's critical need for my project. Tnak you in advance.

i have tried to increase the timedout "export CYPRESS_VERIFY_TIMEOUT=100000",
i tried to install and reinstall cypress, i had cypress 12.13.0 and now it's cypress12.14.0
i have tried all combination of uninstall of cypress:
npm uninstall cypress --save-dev
clear cypress cache
npm install cypress --save-dev

Comment: looks like you have cypress verification time out error. try to run 'npx cypress verify' coommand . this link might be helpful to you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63667880/cypress-verification-timed-out-after-30000-milliseconds

Answer (score 0):

This happens because there's a verification that's meant to happen for first-time users but for some reason, the verification process times out.so one way to make the verification work is by using the npx cypress verify package. run this command in your root folder:

```
npx cypress verify
```

Comment: I have tried this but also the command "npx cypress verify" failed with the same timed out. i have tried to increase the timedout "export CYPRESS_VERIFY_TIMEOUT=100000" with no success.